# After installing updates, Windows 7 reboots when it gets to "Preparing to Configure"

Tags: windows-7, updates

After letting Windows 7 Pro install updates at shutdown I now cannot get it to boot back up. I have tried selecting safemode, and "last known working configuration" and I get the same results.

It gets to the screen and says "Preparing to configure Windows" and then reboots. If it is giving me a BSOD it is happening so fast I can not see it.

This is a generic PC that has been running fine for the last year. It had 22 updates to do at shutdown.

Windows 7 Pro Service Pack 1 64 bit in an Active Directory Domain.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get your system back by using the recovery disk and loaded your last safe setting from system restore.

You can then attempt to update again and see if you get the same problem.

Although I have not experienced this problem with 7 I did with Vista a while back. It would always download updates on shutdown and then then install on boot(every time). Sometimes but not everytime it would hang.

I ended up having the manually install the updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try out a restore for your windows. If you have not the disc to restore it then you can find it on any helping forum they provide the ISO image of windows 7 to just recover its error you can't install the windows from that image disc but you can repair your PC.  Here is a [link](http://www.proposedsolution.com/downloads/download-windows-7-vista-bootable-disc-cd-dvd-iso-image/) for you hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You may have the Windows Recovery Environment on your hard drive, use F8 at the bios splash screen to load the Advanced Boot Options Menu, then choose "Repair your Computer" and hit enter.

Then you can do a Windows System Restore, pick a date before the updates were installed.

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial142.html

.

[image]